# Error while restoring Postgres DB Dump

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, restore, errors

Using below command to restore the database

Restoration command:

```
cat my_db_dump.sql.gz | gunzip | psql -d new_database -U my_username
```

Note: my_db_dump.sql.gz size is 4.5 GB, (extracted size will be around 70 GB)

Getting the below exception (after executing above restoration command)

> gunzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
>   ERROR:  unterminated quoted string at or near "'\x3c3f78
>   (hexadecimal junks removed)
>   LINE 1: SELECT pg_catalog.lowrite(0, '\x3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d...

Comment: Not really proficient in Linux shell, but shouldn't that be `gunzip -c my_db_dump.sql.gz | psql ...`?

Comment: same command (restoration command) was working fine earlier. so, I hope no issue with command syntax. db size might be an issue? or any corrupted format data in tuple?

Comment: you can also use zcat my_db_dump.sql.gz | psql -d new_database -U my_username

Answer (score 1):

Based on the first error message, the .gz backup file seems to be truncated.

This could be confirmed with the command:

```
gunzip -c my_db_dump.sql.gz >/dev/null
```

Presumably this will lead to the same error message: `unexpected end of file` which is the root cause, the other error from postgres being the consequence of the abrupt end of the data stream.

If the `.gz` file is a copy resulting from a transfer, you want to compare its size against the size of the original, and transfer it again if it's incomplete. If that's the only copy or if the original itself is incomplete, completing the restore will not be possible.

Comment: Problem with the zipped file, found the issue. Thanks.